# @Autowired does not work Spring 3

Tags: spring, autowired

I looked all around to find a solution and couldn't find.

I am using Tomcat, Spring 3 with the jars:

```
org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

and my code is like this:

```
public class EmailResource {
@Autowired
EmailManager emailManager;
}
```

in applicationContext I have:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="emailManager" class="com.mycompany.manager.impl.EmailManagerImpl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.component" />
```

and the web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

However, the emailManager is always null! What am I missing?

**EDITED**

The EmailResource is jersey servlet for rest calls and is defined like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.resource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How do you create EmailResource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a Jersey/Spring connecter to get Jersey to recognize your Spring context on startup.

Replace:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.resource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

With:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
   ....
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

You'll also need the jersey-spring dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After about three hours of pain and questioning my own Spring knowledge (why stuff won't autowire despite the same config I've used many times), I came across this.  Thank you so much.

Comment: if anyone is trying to use this approach with Spring 4, it will still work, but you will get NoSuchMethodException because the version of Spring AOP this dependency is pulling in is not good. I got around it by explicitly excluding the aop dependency in my maven pom:
`<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.18</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Jersey servlet is specified in web.xml as a servlet and thus is not under control of Spring. Spring can't wire the dependencies.

I don't know much about Jersey, but I found [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/restful-web-applications) that is maybe useful to you.

Further, you've to consider EmailManager is an instance variable of a Servlet, and you declared it as Spring Singleton (the default):

```
<bean id="emailManager" class="com.mycompany.manager.impl.EmailManagerImpl" />
```

Thus emailManager should not have any state or it will be non-thread safe.

To explain the problem: suppose that emailManager contains a state, such as a destination address, a subject and a message body. Since is defined as a Singleton, there is only one instance for the whole application. If the servlet is called at the same time by two different people, it could happen that the first process inserts the subject and that same subject is rewritten by the second process before the first was able to send the email. So the data of the two emails will be mixed.

Alternatively it can be defined with scope request, so each request will have a different instance.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about EmailManager and Spring Singleton

Comment: See above, I've edited my answer because it was a little long for a comment.

Comment: My problem is that in the post the writer suggests using @Inject while it's deprecated..

Comment: [@Inject](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) is not deprecated. On the contrary is the new standard way set to replace Autowired. I didn't use it yet, I am using Autowired. Anyway, I think, you'll get an answer from someone expert in Jersey and Spring, unfortunately I don't know how to help you further.